# Не выводятся аргументы консольного приложения в области "Аргументы приложения" Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Не могу вывести аргументы в конколь из области "Аргументы приложения". В интернете говорят, что это может быть из-за разных установленных платформ, но я в своём проекте изменять их даже не могу. Создал даже новый проект, перекинул туда код, но ничего не изменилось. Всё та же проблема.

Я только изучаю C# и не имею ни малейшего представления, что ни так. Что-то в моём коде или в настройках Visual Studio?

[image: Аргументы приложения]

```
using System;

namespace TestCode
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string savePassword = "password12";

            string login = GetString("Enter your login:");
            string password = GetString("Enter password: ");

            if (password == savePassword)
            {
                OutLineResult("", $"{login} enter the System");
            }
            else
            {
                byte attempt = 1;

                do
                {
                    OutLineError($"Wrong password. You have {3 - attempt} more attempts left");
                    password = GetString("Enter password: ");
                    attempt++;
                    if (password == savePassword)
                    {
                        OutLineResult("", $"{login} enter the System");
                        break;
                    }
                } while (attempt < 3);

                Console.WriteLine(attempt);
                if (attempt >= 3)
                {
                    OutLineError("\nThe number of available tries have been exceeded");
                }
            }
        }

        static string GetString(string text)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(text);
            Console.ForegroundColor = Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            string s = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
            return s;
        }

        static int GetInt(string text)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(text);
            Console.ForegroundColor = Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            int i = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
            return i;
        }

        static int GetUInt(string text)
        {
            int d;
            do
            {
                Console.Write(text);
                Console.ForegroundColor = Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                d = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                if (d < 0)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("The number of digits cannot be negative\n");
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                }
            }
            while (d < 0);
            return d;
        }

        static double GetDouble(string text)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(text);
            Console.ForegroundColor = Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            double d = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
            return d;
        }

        static void OutLineResult(string text, string result)
        {
            Console.Write(text);
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
        }

        static void OutLineError(string text)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine(text);
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `string[] args` - вот аргументы. Вы их никак не используете в своём коде.

Comment: Я не понимаю, как именно я должен это сделать

Answer (score -1):

args это массив строковых параметров, которые ваша программа получает на входе.
Типа при запуске из консоли:

```
    c:\> TestCode аргумент0 аргумент1
```

Если же запускаете из VS (при отладке), то строки аргументов берутся из области "Аргументы приложения".
А в программе вы должны проверить типа:

```
if (args.Length > 0)
{
  if (args[0]=="аргумент0")
  {....}
}
```